# Swift Delegate method never getting called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

I have declared my protocol like below in the modal

```
protocol MapViewControllerDelegate : class {
    //func mapViewLocationSelected(sender:AnyObject, location:CLLocation, address:String)
    func didSelectMap(sender:AnyObject)
}
```

Also I've declared the delegate as below

```
weak var delegate : MapViewControllerDelegate?
```

Then I dismiss the screen and invoke delegate method as below

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
delegate?.didSelectMap(self)
```

In the viewcontroller which invoked the model I have following things

Declared the Modal VC as below

```
var mvController : MapViewController = MapViewController()
```

Then I set the delegate as below under `viewDidLoad`

```
mvController.delegate = self
```

Then I implemented the delegate methods

```
func didSelectMap(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Came here")
}
```

But I never came to `ddidSelectMap` method. I've done this before and it worked, I couldn't figure out what went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

parent viewcontroller pastebin.com/7z5vg6yJ

model viewcontroller  pastebin.com/DwAa6erQ

Could it be a problem caused due to MapKit I'm using?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is delegate == nil when you call it?
I check your code. And I didn't see where you push/present mvController from NewPostViewController

Comment: Yes R.K I can see that it's a nil when I put a linebreak and check.. Why is that?

Comment: This is because you present and assign delegate to different controllers, I think

Comment: I'm assigning the delegate to the correct one but may be ARC playing havoc? How do you usually assign delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to assign the delegate in the `prepareForSegue` method. Also make sure to use the `segue.destinationViewController` to get the appropriate VC.

Something like below would do I assume.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMapviewSegue"{
            mapVController = segue.destinationViewController as! MapViewController
            mapVController.delegate = self
        }
}
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks thanks :) You are the savior. Yeah assigning delegate this way worked.

Answer (score 0):

First call delegate and then dismiss the controller. That may solve your problem

```
 delegate?.didSelectMap(self)
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don't think that's an issue @iRealMe

Comment: Yeah that didn't fix the issue. Still the delegate method never gets fired.